# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Lan Driver for Atheros AR8132

Tags: drivers, atheros, lan

Is it possible to install a driver for lan Atheros AR8132 network card on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?  I have an error like peripheral not supported when I clic on the wifi icon.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `linux-generic-lts-quantal`. This will activate the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), which will upgrade the Linux kernel in your 12.04 LTS to the version in Quantal (12.10). That kernel (3.5.0) has built-in support for the `alx` driver, which you need.